# Finding Cumulative progress with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table as below :

[image]

I need to calculate the cumulative progress.

for example S1000 have three f1 score. the progress calculation formula is
(95 - 87) + (87 - 80)

for S2000 the calculation would be (75 -17) + (17 -57)

How to achieve this using SQL

Comment: Are there always 3 rows per group?

Comment: tag your specific database

Comment: @Stu More than 3 records per group, data might have n number of records in a group. Need to calculate the cumulative progress and generic formula would be (row2 - row1) + (row3 - row2) + (row4 -row3).....

Comment: @drum database is SQL

Comment: @KathiravanKesavan , sql is a query language , what is your DBMS? database engine?

Comment: @eshirvana  its MqSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your progress score is the last minus the first.  If there are always three scores, you can use conditional aggregation like this:

```
select college_id, student_id,
       sum(case when f1 = 3 then score
                when f1 = 1 then - score
           end) as progress
from t
group by college_id, student_id;
```

If there are not always three scores, you can generalize this:

```
select college_id, student_id,
       sum(case when f1 = cnt then score
                when f1 = 1 then - score
           end) as progress
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by college_id, student_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
group by college_id, student_id;
```